# MySQL returns empty set when empty table is referenced in the query (even if it's unused)

Tags: mysql

I am executing a following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.user_id, users.email, users.irc_nickname FROM users, user_group_map, user_locale_map WHERE (1=1) GROUP BY users.user_id ORDER BY users.email;
```

This query is concatenated from a few pieces, thus is a bit suboptimal (it references three tables, but only selects from one), but that should not be the problem. The problem is that when the `user_locale_map` table happens to be empty, MySQL returns an empty set for the result. But as soon as I add at least one row to that table, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO user_group_map values(2,1);
```

, I start getting the expected result.

Could anyone enlighten me about what's going on an why? Is this a bug in MySQL, or is it expected behavior? If latter, how can I work it around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select statement does a Cartesian product of the tables.
The WHERE clause is then used as a filter to reduce the size of the result set.

An empty table in the input will results in an empty output set (even before there WHERE clause is applied).

What you are looking for is an `OUTER JOIN` (google it).

An example using MYSQL syntax (because that is that I used most recently).
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/outer-join-simplification.html

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.user_id, users.email, users.irc_nickname
FROM user_group_map
RIGHT JOIN users            ON (user_id)
RIGHT JOIN user_locale_map  ON (user_id)
WHERE (1=1)
GROUP BY users.user_id
ORDER BY users.email;
```

Here member of user and user_locale_map may be NULL

Comment: Thanks! I think you left a little mistake in your query, but it helped me. Here's what I ended up with: `SELECT DISTINCT users.user_id, users.email, users.irc_nickname FROM users LEFT JOIN user_group_map USING (user_id) LEFT JOIN user_locale_map USING (user_id) WHERE (1=1) GROUP BY users.user_id ORDER BY users.email;`

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a cross join on "users, user_group_map, user_locale_map" so if one of the tables is empty no results will be retured, it is a bit like multiplying by zero... you always get zero. You may want to investigate other types of join such as "left join" which will include all the records in a particular table even if the other tables are empty.

Answer (score 1):

The `SELECT` from multiple joins performs a Cartessian product of the tables.

The Cartessian product of any set with the empty set is always empty.

It might be better practice to do something different depending on what the goal of the query is